# Python failed building wheel for dlib Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, pip, dlib

I am attempting to install dlib to my python virtual environment.

There is a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235743/ubuntu-python-unable-to-pip-install-dlib-failed-building-wheel-for-dlib-and-m) and I followed the exact steps to no avail.

Somehow I am able to import dlib when running code and I managed to do that by git cloning `git clone -b pybind11 https://github.com/supervacuus/dlib.git`.

But when I attempt to install it **pip3 install dlib** or a library that depends on it such as **pip3 install face_recognition** I get errors stating that ***ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib***

Full execution logs and error here https://gist.github.com/GhettoBurger996/1e6a423b88b7435c8759255e19fa5e60

I am using 3.5.2 and Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 6):

Question is a bit old but I ran into a similar problem where installing dlib using pip3 would fail.

Installing the following dependencies fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

From the posted error logs it seems that you had cmake installed already so the first line might not be necessary for you.

Answer (score 0):

Python development headers are files used for compiling C/C++ code that interfaces with the Python programming language. These header files define the Python API and are essential when you're building C/C++ extensions for Python, or any other code that needs to interact with the Python interpreter at a low level. Without these headers, the compiler won't have the necessary information to interact with the Python runtime. They are typically needed when installing packages with parts written in C/C++, like dlib.

So first install Python dev version by this command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
#It may depends on which version of python3 you are using
```

Now install dlib by using this command (Make sure install cmake before it)

```
pip install dlib
```