# How to install dlib on Ubuntu VPS on digital ocean

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, dlib

I have created a `ubuntu` vps which has below specs:

`Linux ubuntu-sh5tb8912admin 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have to run `pthon flask web app` on it and for it I need to install `dlib`. I have tried all the `whl` files mentioned in this [link](https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/) but all I am getting is

`dlib-19.8.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I simply download them using `wget dlib-xxxx-xx.whl` and then install using `pip3 install dlib-xxxx-xx.whl` but it gives me above error. I have a `python 3.6.8` installed

Can anyone please help how can I install dlib.?

Answer (score 0):

If the wheels have a win in their name I guess they are windows-releases not for GNU/Linux. Did you try downloading one of the tar.gz files those should be the ones for Linux.

Comment: Yes I have tried building the dlib from the tar.gz files. I have a 1gb of VPS and it says `virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory` while compiling dlib

Comment: I don't know any repository containing wheels for linux so I guess building a wheel in a different machine with more memory available and then using that wheel to install it in your target environment is your best option.

Comment: Do you know where the wheel files are stored when we build the package. I have built it on another machine and can use the whl file

Comment: Should be in dist folder created by the building process.

Answer (score -2):

```
git clone https://github.com/Universe-ML21/script_install_dlib.git
sudo chmod +x script_install_dlib/auto_dlib.sh
bash script_install_dlib/auto_dlib.sh
```